# Compose an array of strings during compilation

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make an array (or vector, list, w/e) of strings during compilation if each element of the array is in a different file?

Example: I have class my_string. I instantiate it at two different classes. In the end I have one array that contains the two my_string objects. The two classes get pointer/reference to the objects in the array. The important part is that the whole thing should happen during compilation, not run time or initialization.

file1.cpp:

`MyString str1("Hello");`

file2.cpp:

`MyString str2("World");`

file3.cpp would look like this:

`const char* strings[] = {"Hello", "World"};`

str1 & str2 contains pointer/ref/index of the strings object in the file3cpp.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code to make your question clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an array of pointers that gets assembled at compile time:

file1.cpp:

```
char const * str_f1 = "hello";
```

file2.cpp:

```
char const * str_file2 = "world";
```

file3.cpp"

```
extern char const * str_file1, * str_file2;
char const * strs[] { str_file1, str_file2 };
```

Comment: I am more looking for a way to have the following:


file1.cpp
`MyString str("hello");`


file2.cpp
`MyString str("world");`


which ends up like this in file3.cpp:
`charconst* str[] { "hello", "world" };`

Comment: @Moon4u How is that different? You might want to clarify in your question

Comment: the difference is that if I have 1000 such strings, I don't have to manage 2000 variables.